# React question// how to omit duplicate data in array,

Tags: reactjs, filter, reduce

```
  const dayone = [{ name: 1, uid: 1 }, { name: 2, uid: 2 }, { name: 3, uid: 3 },
    { name: "ball", uid: 100 }, { name: "lina", uid: 200 }, { name: "ppp", uid: 700 }]

    const daytwo = [{ name: "ball", uid: 100 }, { name: "lina", uid: 200 }, { name: "ppp", uid: 700 }, { name: 7, uid: 7 }]

    const total = dayone.concat(daytwo)
```

i want to omit the duplicate objects..
{ name: "ball", uid: 100 }, { name: "lina", uid: 200 }, { name: "ppp", uid: 700 }

what i really want to get is,

```
Newtotal = [{ name: 1, uid: 1 }, { name: 2, uid: 2 }, { name: 3, uid: 3 },{ name: 7, uid: 7 }]
```

how can i solve this problem? help!

i am trying to omit the data which is duplicate in array.

i already used filter, map, reduce.. and other friends told me about omit.

but i couldn't find the way how to resolve problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one helps you.

```
[...new Map(total.map((item) => [item["uid"], item])).values(),];
```

```js
  const dayone = [{ name: 1, uid: 1 }, { name: 2, uid: 2 }, { name: 3, uid: 3 },
    { name: "ball", uid: 100 }, { name: "lina", uid: 200 }, { name: "ppp", uid: 700 }]

    const daytwo = [{ name: "ball", uid: 100 }, { name: "lina", uid: 200 }, { name: "ppp", uid: 700 }, { name: 7, uid: 7 }]

    const total = dayone.concat(daytwo)
const unique = [
    ...new Map(total.map((item) => [item["uid"], item])).values(),
];
console.log("original items",total.length,total)
console.log("unique items",unique.length,unique)
```

Thanks.